# XM cloud software prerequisites

Tags: xm-cloud

What are the software prerequisites for XM cloud migration from XP(Paas hosting)
like Visual Studio
.Net core and framework version
Sql and IIS(if needed)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the prerequisites for running the XM Cloud started kit locally on your own machine.

**Running Docker on Windows 10**:
To run Docker on Windows 10, you must have the following:

- Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise version 1903 or later. For enabling process isolation, you must have version 1909, or later.
- Enable Hyper-V.
- The Docker Desktop installer enables Hyper-V if necessary, but a machine restart is then required during install.

**Hardware guidelines**: The hardware must meet the requirements for running Hyper-V. For complete details, including how to verify compatibility, see Windows 10 Hyper-V System Requirements. To summarize, Hyper-V requires:

- A 64 bit processor with Second-level address translation (SLAT) and hardware-assisted virtualization.
- At least 4GB of RAM (see the further requirements for XM cloud that follow).
- Virtualization support must be turned on in the BIOS.

In addition to the Hyper-V requirements, XM Cloud development has the following further requirements:

- 16GB of RAM is the minimum, 32GB of RAM is recommended. This depends on the number of instances you want to run (that is, the number of simultaneously running containers).
- A quad core, or higher, CPU.
- At least 30GB of free disk space for XM Cloud container images. SSD storage is highly recommended for optimal performance when downloading and running Docker containers

Refer to this for more details: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/preparing-to-run-the-xm-cloud-starter-kit-locally.html

You must have the following software components on your workstation:

- A valid Sitecore license file.
- Windows PowerShell 5.1. (PowerShell 7 is not supported at this time).
- The current long-term support (LTS) version of Node.js.
- .NET Core 6.0 SDK (check your installed version with the dotnet --version command).
- .NET Framework 4.8 SDK (see the Microsoft procedure for checking .NET Framework versions).
- Visual Studio 2022.
- Docker for Windows, with Windows Containers enabled.

Any required components for using Sitecore Containers.

Refer this for more details: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--setting-up-your-full-stack-xm-cloud-local-development-environment.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before XM Cloud development work, the below prerequisites is necessary to set up.

- Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise version 1903 or later
- Docker Desktop, with Windows containers enabled
- Nodejs 16.15.1 and  npm 8.11.0
- .NET Core 3.1 SDK
- .NET Framework 4.8 SDK
- Visual Studio  2022

If you are using the VSCode editor, here is the recommended list of extensions to install:

- Docker
- ESLint
- Markdown All in One
- markdownlint
- Prettier - Code formatter
- Prettier ESLint
- Stylelint
- Tailwind CSS
- ...

There is a detailed tutorial for you to start https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/developer-tools/set-up-the-environment.html.

Furthermore there is a official demo repo at Github for starters which you can refer to for more details at https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.XmCloud.PlaySummit/tree/main/docs.

Hope it helps!